# R - Fast subsetting large data table conditioned on a list of data frame

Tags: r, data.table, subset, large-data

I have a data table and a list of data frame formatted as follows:

```
require(data.table)
members = c('a','b','c')
DT = do.call('rbind',
         lapply(members, function(x){
             date = seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), as.Date("2015/12/31"), 'days')
             dummy = sample(length(date))
             dt = data.table(member=sample(x, length(dummy), replace=TRUE), date=date, dummy=dummy)} 
         )
     )

date = seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), as.Date("2015/12/31"), 'days')
l.members = lapply(members, function(x){
                n.period = sample(10,1)
                do.call('rbind',
                    lapply(1:n.period, function(y){
                        period = sample(date, 2)
                        if (period[1]>period[2]){
                            start=period[2]
                            due=period[1]
                        }else{
                            start=period[1]
                            due=period[2]
                        }
                        return(data.frame(start.date=start, due.date=due))}
                    )
                )
            })
names(l.members) = members
```

`DT` is the large (about 4G as csv file) data table from which I want to subset based on the `l.members`. Every name of entry *x* in `l.members` is one of the members in `unique(DT$member)`. In every entry there is a data frame with each row representing a period [*p1*, *p2*], based on which I want to subset the rows in `DT` with `DT$member` is *x* and `DT$date` => *p1* and `DT$date` <= *p2*. The current workaround is as follows:

```
l.member.periods = lapply(members,
                       function(x){
                           DT.member = DT[member==x]
                           apply(l.members[[x]], 1,
                               function(y){
                                   start = y[1]
                                   due = y[2]
                                   return(DT.member[date>=start&date<=due])
                               }
                           )
                        }
                   )
```

It takes decades when there are about 5000 entries in `l.members`, each of which has mostly 10 rows (periods). I've tried replacing `lapply` with `mclapply` but doesn't seem to work, it ends up drying the memory and hanging. How can I speed up the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `foverlaps`.
First, you need to store `l.members` as a `data.table`

```
lmembers <- rbindlist(lapply(1:length(l.members), 
                             function(i)data.table(member=names(l.members)[i], 
                                                   l.members[[i]], 
                                                   keep.rownames = TRUE)))

> head(lmembers)
   member rn start.date   due.date
1:      a  1 2015-03-30 2015-04-29
2:      a  2 2015-03-25 2015-12-07
3:      a  3 2015-02-06 2015-03-01
4:      a  4 2015-09-19 2015-11-08
5:      a  5 2015-06-23 2015-08-27
6:      a  6 2015-04-22 2015-10-08
```

Next step is the obvious use of `foverlaps`.

```
setkey(lmembers, "member", "start.date", "due.date")
DT[, date1:=date,]
setkey(DT, "member","date", "date1")
lmemberperiods <- foverlaps(lmembers, DT)[, .(member, rn, date, dummy)]
```

Check that this results in a desired outcome.

```
lmemberperiods[member=="a" & rn==1]
l.member.periods[[1]][[1]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, clever use of type='any' and appending date1.

Comment: If I want to do something on each `rn` of each `member`, what would be the recommended way? By now I split `l.member.periods` to a list of members, each of which has a list of rn, and I use nested `lapply` to do the job. Maybe there is a faster methodology?